# How can I select an image and put the link of the image in a textbox?

Tags: php, jquery, image, select

I have a form `SelectIamge.php` which includes the following html:

```
<input type="text" id="urlImage" />
<input type="button" id="selectImage" />
```

The user needs to be able to click the selectImage button to open a popup of page UploadImage.php. The user will then upload a image and a thumbnail of that image will be displayed. If the user clicks on the thumbnail, I need to put the url of the image in the urlImage textbox.

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: .:you can use, javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

First of all give some id to thumbnail image i.e id='thumb'

Include jquery library file and write below javascript in the file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#thumb").click(function(){
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   $("#urlImage").val(src);
});
</script>
```

Comment: This code will put on form SelectIamge.php  or UploadImage.php ?? Thanks you very much!

Comment: Can someone instructions me more detail??

Comment: It should be put in the page where your urlimage id exists, I think in selectimage.php